# Do I need to setup Glacier Vault to archive data from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I'm really new to AWS and quite confused on the purpose of Glacier vault, when I can archive my objects thru S3 via lifecycle rule? so do I have to first setup Glacier Vault for me to archive my objects?

Answer (score 3):

Once upon a time, there was a service called **Amazon Glacier**. It was very low-cost, but it was very painful to use. Every request (even listing the contents of a vault) took a long time (eg make a request, come back an hour later to get the result).

Then, the clever people in Amazon S3 realized that they could provide a more friendly interface to Glacier. By simpler changing the **storage class** of objects in S3 to `Glacier`, they would move the files to their own Glacier vault and save you all the hassle.

Then, the S3 team introduced `Glacier Deep Archive`, which is only available via Amazon S3 and is even *lower cost* than Glacier itself!

The children rejoiced and all cried out in unison... *"We will now only use Glacier via S3. We will never go direct to Glacier again!"*

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to. You use Glacier Vaults if you want to use extra features that [S3 Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/introduction.html) service provides, such as [Vault Lock Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-lock.html) and/or [Vault Access Policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/vault-access-policy.html).

For using just the Glacier storage, you can use [Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html) service and lifecycle rules.